# AngularJS error, $scope.gridApi is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a weird problem with the AngularJS ui-grid. Since I'm not an expert with AngularJS (I had never worked with it until I started working on this project) I thought perhaps I was missing something really obvious.

The grid is set up to have four types of columns: read-only, input, output, and combination input/output columns. I set up code to allow the user to decide which columns he or she wants to display, all, input, output, or input and output columns.

At the end of my function I want to refresh the grid to make the change visible. I have debugged the rest of the function and have stepped through it to prove to myself that the code is executing properly right up to the last line which is where I'm getting the error.

I have done a lot of searching here and none of the results have solved my problem. The controller where my function is defined also defines an onRegisterApi method and assigned gridApi to $scope.gridApi. I've stepped through the code and onRegisterApi *is* executed. Yet whenever my code hits the last line of my function which is:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
```

I always get an error that $scope.gridApi is undefined.

I would say that it was just a matter of me trying to refer to something outside its scope, but if I place a breakpoint on the line and add a watch for $scope.gridApi, I can see that not only is it defined but that it contains core and that core contains a refresh() method.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code. It is defined under $scope.models:

```
    api: {
        newOption: function (option) {
            var colViewOptionType = option.colViewOptionType;
            var numColumns = $scope.myGrid.columnDefs.length;
            var viewWhat = "??";
            switch (colViewOptionType) {
                case 'All':
                    // Show all columns
                    viewWhat = 'all columns.';
                    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++)
                    {
                        $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'I/O':
                    // Show columns that are either input or output columns
                    viewWhat = 'Input/Output Columns.';
                    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                        if ($scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].cellClass == 'inputField')
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = true;
                        else if($scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].cellClass == 'outputField')
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = true;
                        else
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Input':
                    // Show columns that are for input only.
                    viewWhat = 'Input only columns.';
                    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                        if ($scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].cellClass == 'inputField')
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = true;
                        else
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Output':
                    // Show columns that are for output only.
                    viewWhat = 'Output only columns.';
                    for (var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
                        if ($scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].cellClass == 'outputField')
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = true;
                        else
                            $scope.myGrid.columnDefs[i].visible = false;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            $scope.gridApi.core.refresh();
            // I added this for debugging purposes.
            alert("You chose to view: " + viewWhat);
        }

    }
},
```

Comment: Could you share some more of your code?

Comment: I shared the relevant parts of the code. Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that this is a scope (variable scope, not $scope) issue but I'm have a very hard time wrapping my mind around JavaScript scope.

Comment: Apparently I was right about the scope problem. I solved that part by assigning a copy of gridApi at the document level. It's a really kludgy fix but the only thing that worked. As far as updating the view, I found that I was wasting my time with changing the visibility directly and used hideColumn()/showColumn() instead. Coming up with this solution was a very painful process and I'm disappointed that nobody bothered to point out the obvious (to someone who has been using angular and ui-grid, that is) problem in my code.